# Find the number of positive integer solutions to the equation $a^2+b^2 = p_1p_2p_3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

Find the number of positive integer solutions to the equation
$$a^2+b^2 = p_1p_2p_3 $$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes each congruent to $1$ mod $4$.

**My take**:

We can show each $p_i$ can be written as a sum of two squares since they are congruent to $1$ mod $4$, and also that such a representation is unique.
We know that the product of sum of two squares is a sum of two squares since $(x^2+y^2)(z^2+w^2) = (xz+yw)^2 + (xw-yz)^2 = (xz-yw)^2 + (xw+yz)^2$

So $p_1p_2$ can be written as a sum of two squares in two ways and for each such representation $(p_1p_2)p_3$ can be written as a sum of two squares in two ways. So in all, $p_1p_2p_3$ can be written as a sum of two squares in $4$ ways.

So it seems there are $4$ solutions to the given equation (not considering ordered pairs).

Am I missing any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the smallest values of $p1, p2, p3 = 5, 13, 17$, we get that $5*13*17 = 1105$.

For this, we have $a = 23, b = 24$ || $a = 33, b = 4$ || $a = 32, b = 9$ || $a = 31, b = 12$.

That makes 4 for the first set, at least.

I believe there are none for $p1, p2, p3 = 5, 13, 29$. The actual theory, I have no idea.

Comment: If $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$, $p_1p_2p_3$ can always be written as a sum of two squares. One representation for $\{5,13,29\}$ is $5\times13 \times 29 = 1885 = 21^2+ 38^2$.

Comment: So, there are going to be more than 4 solutions? Are there infinite solutions?